# Why I obtain this error message related to "rtl120.bpl" file missing on my Windows 10 system?

Tags: windows, windows-10, anti-virus, dll

I have the following problem. Trying to execute a **.exe** file on my **Windows 10** system I obtain an error message that says that is impossible to run the program because the **rtl120.bpl** file is not on my computer and try to reintstall it.

From what I read online it seems that it is a file related to **Panda Antivirus** but I never installed Panda on this computer.

What could be the problem? How can I try to fix it?

Comment: That .exe file was built in Delphi 4. it has a dependency on rtl120.bpl which is a redistributable and should come along with this exe's installer. It has no relation with Panda Antivirus

Comment: @AEonAX Ok but I have not this rtl120.bpl so what can I do? Can I download somewhere? Where have I to put it? How can I obtain it?

Comment: Installer of this exe? When you get the file you need to put it in same folder as exe. I think you cannot obtain it legally unless distributed by the exe's provider.

Comment: Reinstall the program in question and is that still doesn't work, contact the author of the program, and report that the installer is broken